# Create a new variable for every row in dataframe column

Tags: pandas, loops, assign

I'm trying to create a series of variables based on an existing df column. Example :

```
import pandas as pd

dates = {'expiries': ['10','11','13','14']}
expiries = pd.DataFrame(dates)
expiries
```

I then want to create a new variable (var1 through var4) giving it the value from each row. I know I can get it by going:

```
var1 = expiries['expiries'].iloc[0]
var2 = expiries['expiries'].iloc[1]
var3 = expiries['expiries'].iloc[2]
var4 = expiries['expiries'].iloc[3]
```

but in reality my df is a variable length and I need a variable per row not a pre determined (hardcoded) number of variables.

Comment: The question is why? If you don't know the number of variables, how do you type them? Are you looking into some sort of `for` loop?

Comment: you can store in a dict : `expiries['expiries'].to_dict()` and refer the keys later if really required,  since creating variables from a loop isnt a great idea. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Comment: I'm using the variables to create columns in a new df. I then reference that df with some visualisations. An initial product selection determines the number of expiries. Sometimes 15 sometimes 20. If I preset the variables to 20, when my product only has 15 the visualisations dont run as they are missing columns. Appreciate the advice that its anti code logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store them in the dict:

```py
var_dict = {}
for i in range(expires.shape[0]):
    var_dict['var' + str(i+1)] = expiries['expiries'].iloc[i]
```

it is against coding logic that you have unknown number of variables

Answer (score 1):

you could use `exec`

```
for row in expiries.itertuples():
    idx, value = row
    exec(f'var{idx+1} = {value}')

print(var1, var2, var3, var4)
>>>
10 11 13 14
```